# killing a rosrun process using python script

Tags: ros, python, thread, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am writing a GUI interface to run nodes in ROS. The following code execute a rosrun process when pressing Button1.
I looked for a code in order to kill that process when pressing Button 2. I did not find something specific or related to this work.

#simple GUI

```
import os, time, signal, threading
from Tkinter import * 
from subprocess import call
from subprocess import Popen  
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import cv2
#from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PIL import *


def f1():
    subprocess.Popen(["rosrun", "package_name", "nodename"])
def f2():
    // NEED CODE HERE 


root.title("root") 
root.geometry("500x500") 
button1 = Button(root,text="CORE", bg="black", fg="white",  width=25, padx = 20, command=f1)
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(root,text="CORE", bg="black", fg="white",  width=25, padx = 20, command=f2)
button2.pack()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221077/killing-a-rosrun-process-using-python-script/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-17**:
Have you tried just killing the opened process with normal functionality from the subprocess module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `subprocess.Popen` instantiator inside of your `f1()` function returns a `subprocess.Popen` instance. That object has a `kill` method that allows you to terminate subprocesses. A simple re-write could be something like

```
proc = None
def f1():
    global proc
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["rosrun", "package_name", "nodename"])
def f2():
    proc.kill()
```

Alternatively, if you are going to be spawning ROS nodes, you could use [rosnode.kill_nodes](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rosnode/html/) to shutdown nodes that you have started.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2015-11-28**:
Thank you :) it worked perfectly